# Не работает адаптивная верстка

Tags: html, css, css3, media-queries

В общем, есть: прописано в стилях!

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1360px){
.wrapper-responsive {
    background-color: #000000;
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px){
.wrapper-responsive {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}}
```

также, в хеде прописал это:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

и еще в стилях указал это в

```
.wrapper-responsive {
    min-width: 1280px;
    max-width: 1360px;
}
```

При изменении разрешения экрана, не срабатывает стиль. и почему-то всегда по умолчанию применяется вот этот стиль:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1280px){
    .wrapper-responsive {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }}
```

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 1361px){ так сработает?

Comment: Игорь, на каком экране не срабатывает?

Comment: при размере 1360x768 выдает стиль 1280x800

при смене разрешения  на 1280x800 выдает стиль 1280x800

Comment: @ИгорьБолдырев , если задача актуальна, дайте ссылку на страницу с ошибкой.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не срабатывает media для блоков?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588383/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-media-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2) UPDATE: Поторопился. Не, не дубликат.

Comment: Попробуй убрать user-scalable

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 1359px) {
    .wrapper-responsive {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема точно в том, что экран не выдает ту ширину, на которой должен работать медиа запрос(у меня так же). ф12 и тести, что и как на разных разрешениях.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  min-width: 1080px;
  max-width: 1260px;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1260px){
  body {
      background: #ad4848;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1079px){
  body {
      background: #000000;
  }
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

и only уже никто не использует, как я понимаю.