# Почему не срабатывает media для блоков?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Здравствуйте. Есть блоки, которые при определенном разрешении экрана должны становиться невидимы. Но у меня почему то не срабатывает. Что я делаю нет так?

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12pt;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .b320 { display: block; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: block; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: block; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: block; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: block; }
}
```

```html
<div class="b320">media: <b>max-width: 320px</b></div>
<div class="b480">media: <b>max-width: 480px</b></div>
<div class="b640">media: <b>max-width: 640px</b></div>
<div class="b768">media: <b>max-width: 768px</b></div>
<div class="b1000">media: <b>max-width: 1000px</b></div>
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: а как вы решили что не работает ?

Comment: @Geyan при изменении размера окна браузера не появляется соответствующая разметка

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/oYXyqo?editors=110 у меня  работает ваша схема

Comment: @Geyan странно. А тут если выполнить кол работает?

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 1000px)` ,` @media screen and (max-width: 768px)` а почему не по убыванию? и так было бы все нормальн

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ширина меньше 320, то она и меньше 1000. А из css-правил выбирается последнее. Поэтому надо просто переставить все блоки в обратном порядке:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: block; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: block; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: block; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: block; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .b320 { display: block; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<div class="b320">media: <b>max-width: 320px</b></div>
<div class="b480">media: <b>max-width: 480px</b></div>
<div class="b640">media: <b>max-width: 640px</b></div>
<div class="b768">media: <b>max-width: 768px</b></div>
<div class="b1000">media: <b>max-width: 1000px</b></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так будет работать:

body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .b320 { display: block; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px){
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: block; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 480px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: block; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 640px){
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: block; }
    .b1000 { display: none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .b320 { display: none; }
    .b480 { display: none; }
    .b640 { display: none; }
    .b768 { display: none; }
    .b1000 { display: block; }
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egaq35ac/), у вас при маленьких разрешениях срабатывают сразу несколько медиазапросов.

Comment: c некоторого времени писать `min-width` в паре с `max-width` писать вроде ни требуется