# Проблема с подключением media.scss | SCSS

Tags: css, scss

Не работает код из **_media.scss**.

**_media.scss**:

```
@media (max-width: 1230px) {
    .nav-link {
        display: none;
    }

    .button-nav {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**main.scss**:

`@import './base/media';`

**Структура проекта**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если подключить через .css, то всё работает. А через .scss не хочет.

Comment: пробовали расширение файлу добавить в импорте?

Comment: @Meth0d дело не в расширении, в scss так устроено. Тут проблема в самом файле _media.scss или в коде. Если создать файл .css, и там написать этот код - работает.

Comment: А Вы смотрели в итоговом файле ```css\main.css``` - туда попадают Ваши стили из scss-файла с медиазапросами?

Comment: @Stark да, стили туда попадают, но не работают.

Comment: Если вы для стилей `display` добавите `!important` ничего не поменяется ?

Comment: Проверьте, есть ли в `main.css` эти стили для `@media` ?

Answer (score 0):

Я полностью повторил вашу структуру и у меня всё работает. Вот главный файл.
[image: test1]
Вот тот который вы пытаетесь подключить.
[image: test2]

Вы либо некорректно подключаете генерируемый `css` файл. (Надо убедиться что туда падают обновления от Watcher-а, не знаю как оно там у Вас генериться...``` gulp``webpack ```? ) либо то, что у Вас отвечает, за генерацию из `SCSS` у вас криво подключено.

Использую `PhpStorm` в качестве редактора, там всё из коробки запускаеться, но если пути слетели, то [вот](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#sass_scss_less_before_you_start) для `PhpStorm`, после того как Нода установлена.

`npm install -g sass`

[image: test]

Answer (score 0):

> да, стили туда попадают, но не работают

Стоп. Раз стили попадают в скомпилированный файл, значит всё настроено верно и ничего делать не надо. А дальше куда-то [сюда](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/178988), ну или сразу [за media](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608331/178988) и [подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/588395/178988).